# Postfix - limit outgoing messages sent by one specific user

Tags: postfix, email-server, rhel8

I want to limit outgoing messages to 5 per hour for a single user. It should then queue any additional messages during that hour to be attempted for delivery later. All other users should not be affected by this limit.

I tried using a slow transport:

```
slow unix - - n - 5 smtp
```

Using a sender-dependent and regular transport map:

```
user@example.com slow:
```

I also tried using postfwd:

```
/user_check/   sender/regexp    =~ /^(user@example\.com)$/ local   hour >= 5   action=rate(sender/3600/5)
```

/etc/postfix/master.cf

```
postfwd unix - n n - 5 smtp
    -o content_filter=
    -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
```

It did not seem to work. Can anyone provide a solution or suggestions to this problem?

OS: CentOS 8
postfix-3.5.20-2.redhat.8+p18.0.55.2+t230919.0741.x86_64